# unity animation ui button

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, uibutton

this code I use it on ui button for change between animation (up,down) for platform, but when I click the up begun and still working I click again the down begun working but it cut the up animation. how can fix that to white the up animation and begun the down?

```
public Animator anim;
private bool move1;
void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}
// Update is called once per frame
public void ChangePlatform () {
    if (move1==true) {
        anim.SetInteger ("animstate",1);
        move1 = false;
    }else if (move1==false) {
        anim.SetInteger ("animstate",2);
        move1 = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand everything in your question, but I think you are looking for the [Exit Time](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transition.html) of your transitions.

> If “Has Exit Time” is enabled, this value represents the exact time at which the transition can take effect

Try to set the value to 1 so that a transition can occur only if the current state is completed. If you set the value to 0, the transition can "interrupt" the current state any  time.